# React warning setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get this Error/Warning in my console:

> setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component.

## EDIT Mounting the component

Here's where I mount the component:

```
componentDidMount()
    {
        if (this.isVisible()) {
            this.setState({visible: true});
        }

        this.bindEventListeners();
    }
```

This is the code that is causing the issue:

```
bindEventListeners()
    {
        let visibilityEvent = function (event) {
            event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(event.type, visibilityEvent);
            // protect the component against unloading
            if (this.isVisible()) {
                this.setState({visible: true});
            }

            // no need to call the timeout when its already visible
            if (!this.state.visible) {
                let scrollEvnt = setTimeout(function () {
                    EventContainer.readWindowEvent('scroll', visibilityEvent);
                }, 100);

                this.setState({scrollEv: scrollEvnt});
            }

        }.bind(this);

        EventContainer.readWindowEvent('scroll', visibilityEvent);
    }
```

This line to be more precise:

> this.setState({scrollEv: scrollEvnt});

If I understand it correctly it means that I need a way to unmount the scroll event. But I am not sure if this is even possible. I am pretty sure you can't unbind a scroll event in (vanilla)javascript/React.

### Edit 2 isVisible function

```
isVisible()
    {
        let isVisible = true;

        try {
            let heightElement = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).getBoundingClientRect().top;

            isVisible = heightElement - window.innerHeight < 0;
        } catch (error) {
            console.warn('Falling back');
        }

        return isVisible;
    }
```

I might be wrong but I am not sure how to resolve this warning/error. Maybe someone can help me out? Any help is appreciated :)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The error means that you called the `setState` function before the component is mounted.

Comment: @AsafDavid Thanks for your response, but I am not sure how I can fix it. I added my componentDidMount function check out edited OP if you want :)

Comment: you probably need to handle componentWillUnmount and remove the event listener there

Comment: @Tom Thanks for your answer! I was aware of this but I am not sure that it is possible to remove a scroll event listener

Comment: you can remove a scroll event listener, yes

Comment: @Tom I have been searching for 2 days and haven't found a way, unfortunately

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll) and window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll)

Answer (score 0):

I think we might need to see more of the code to figure this one out.

A couple of questions:

- Are you sure you're not calling bindEventListeners() from somewhere else?
- Why do you need "this.state.visible" when you have this.isVisible()?

[This diagram has helped me a lot in keeping track of where everything happens in a react object's lifecycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwNw5.jpg)

Comment: Yes I am sure I am not calling bindEventListeners from somewhere else :) and "this.state.visible" checks if the state is already visible: false not the comment `// no need to call the timeout when its already visible`above the code I'll update the OP with the isVisible function

Comment: Makes sense -- I had a similar error recently and it appeared that it was solved by ensuring that setState was only called once for the property in `componentDidMount()` (and the functions it calls). I wonder if it's really necessary to have this bit of code this twice: `if (this.isVisible()) { this.setState({visible: true}); }` (in both `componentDidMount()` AND `bindEventListeners()`)

Comment: Yes because in the componentDidMount it sets it to true, obviously and in the bindEventListeners it makes sures the component unloads it self. I hope you understand what I am trying to say :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the scroll event listener in `componentWillUnmount`

Something along the lines of the following should work:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onScroll = this.onScroll.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount()
{
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
}

componentWillUnmount()
{
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
}

onScroll(event)
{
    //handle event here
}
```